# Angular Routing remove Route Fragment after navigation

Tags: angular

How can I remove an Angular route Fragment after I have navigated to the Route+Fragment?

With my current setup, the route fragment (http://address/#[fragment]) becomes part of the navigated URL, preventing a user that scrolled to a different section on the page, to use the route+fragment a second time. This is as a result of the URL already being in the "jump to" state. Eg. http://localhost:4200/home#shop.

After a user has used the "jump to" route, the URL should change from http://localhost:4200/**home#shop** back to http://localhost:4200/**home**

**My current code**

**This is a "jump to" router link:**

```
<a [routerLink]="['/home']" fragment="shop">shop</a>
```

**In my routing-module.ts:**

```
imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {
    scrollPositionRestoration: 'enabled',
    anchorScrolling: 'enabled',
    scrollOffset: [0, 64]
})],
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to use Location from `@angular/common`.

```
import { Location, LocationStrategy, PathLocationStrategy } from '@angular/common';

constructor(
   private location: Location
) { }

ngOnInit() {
   // replaceState(path: string, query: string = '', state: any = null): void
   this.location.replaceState(pathWithoutHash);
}
```

You can also wait a bit before removing the fragment with a timeout.

[The docs](https://angular.io/api/common/Location)

Comment: Thank you for the solution. It works great for changing the URL. One caveat I am experiencing, is that it does not solve the issue of enabling the "jump to" route fragment (URL/home#shop) for a user to use the "jump to" a second time. Any suggestions would be great

Comment: Maybe try to add a condition to your link. e.g. `private allowFragment: boolean;` and in your link `[fragment]="allowFragment ? 'shop' : ' ' "`.